# Python Musixmatch API - Lyrics Are Not Retrieved Fully

Tags: python, musixmatch

I'm trying to get lyrics for certain tracks from Musixmatch using the Python Musixmatch API. I'm using the `musixmatch.matcher_lyrics_get` function with the artist name and track title, but I'm only getting part pf the lyrics and not the full lyric I need.

Here's a code snippet that demonstrates what output I got vs. what output I was expecting to get:

```
musixmatch = Musixmatch(API_KEY)
response = musixmatch.matcher_lyrics_get("Here Comes the Sun", "The Beatles")
print(response['message']['body']['lyrics']['lyrics_body'])
```

Given output from `print`:

> Here comes the sun, doo-doo-doo-doo
> Here comes the sun, and I say
> It's alright
>
> Little darlin', it's been a long, cold, lonely winter
> Little darlin', it feels like years since it's been here
>
> Here comes the sun, doo-doo-doo-doo
> Here comes the sun, and I say
> It's alright
>
> Little darlin', the smile's returning to their faces
>
> ...
>
> ******* This Lyrics is NOT for Commercial use *******

Desired output: The song's full lyrics, found here:

https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/The-Beatles/here-comes-the-sun

Could anyone help me get the full lyrics instead of only part of them?  Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Musicxmatch api allows to retreive 30% of the lyrics for free version. If you need to obtain full, then you have to contact them for subscribtion.

You can check the same in this [link](https://developer.musixmatch.com/plans)

[A screenshot of the pricing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kjUe.png)